# Is there any jQuery plugin or Rails gem which gives full browser language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I can get browser language using JavaScript

```
<script>
   navigator.language
</script>
```

but I need to get FULL language name and returnt to user. For example

```
ru - Russian
en - English
etc.
```

Is there any plugin or Rails gem, that can help me or should I do this on my own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create it using a simple JSON object.

```
function getFullLanguage(){
  var fullLanguages = {
    "ru": "Russian"
  , "en": "English"
  }
  var lang = navigator.language.substring(0,2);
  return fullLanguages[lang] || "Unknown";
}
```

Here's a full [list of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

Comment: thanks. How can I run it window onload in jQuery and show appropriate value ?

Comment: If you want to insert the resulting language in the DOM using jQuery for example, you can simply do `$("#language").html(getFullLanguage());`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/xCgsb/

Comment: See previous comment. I added a link to a Fiddle there.